# MVC Foolproof Validation not working in Forms application

Tags: vb.net, validation, foolproof-validation

I have added a reference to `MVC Foolproof Validation` to my project.  I am using one of the annotations on my model:

```
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Start Date is required.")>
    <LessThanOrEqualTo("EndDate", ErrorMessage:="Start Date must not be after End Date.")>
    Public Property StartDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return Item.StartDate
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            Item.StartDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="End Date is required.")>
    Public Property EndDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return Item.EndDate
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            Item.EndDate = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

We have a validation class which validates like so:

```
    Dim results As New List(Of ValidationResult)()

    Debug.Assert(model IsNot Nothing)
    Dim modelProperties = New List(Of PropertyInfo)
    GetModelPropertiesRecursively(model.GetType(), modelProperties)

    For Each pi As PropertyInfo In modelProperties
        Dim result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(pi.GetValue(model),
                                      New ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(model, Nothing, Nothing) With {.MemberName = pi.Name}, results)
    Next
    Dim modelName = model.GetType().Name
    Dim mapped = results.Select(Function(result)
                                    Debug.Assert(result.MemberNames.Any())
                                    Return New ValidationError(modelName, result.MemberNames.First(), result.ErrorMessage)
                                End Function)

    For Each validationError As ValidationError In mapped
        context.ValidationErrors.Add(validationError)
    Next
```

This works for all the regular `DataAnnotation`s, but it's not catching it for the new annotation.  I can't debug into `Validator.TryValidateProperty`, but the result comes back as true for the property, despite being after the `EndDate`.

Is the Validation logic flawed?

Comment: Use the second overload of [`Validator.TryValidateProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx) and specify `validateAllProperties = true`. Otherwise the validator will only validate the `Required` attributes.

Comment: My brain must be tired, I was linking to TryValidateObject. Sorry for the mistake. On a sidenote, why not use the TryValidateObject instead of writing the exact same thing in above code?

Comment: @Styxxy Your guess is as good as mine, I didn't write it :) I went ahead and tried it, and it exhibited the same behavior.

Comment: Kyle, it seems like the library is incomplete. The `IsValid` function throws a `NotImplementedException`. The library is also dead. So best thing is to fork it and do some adjustments. Example adjustments: http://pastebin.com/thQERyy2

Comment: @Styxxy I see that it's dead, I'm not seeing that it's incomplete.  The `LessThanOrEqualTo` class only has a constructor to call `Is`, which has a valid implementation of `IsValid`

Comment: The IsValid method you are referring to, is the wrong overload.